# Crash On resume after using other apps

Tags: android, xamarin, mono

App crashes onResume after using other applications (such as Camera). Below is the static constructor:

```
 public static DashboardFragment newInstance(int ZoneIndex, bool isTablet, DashboardActivity Activity)
 {
     Bundle Args = new Bundle();
     Args.PutInt(Constants.Values.ZONE_INDEX, ZoneIndex);
     Args.PutBoolean(Constants.Values.TABLET, isTablet);
     DashboardFragment DashboardFragment = new DashboardFragment();
     DashboardFragment.Arguments = Args;
     _Activity = Activity;
     return DashboardFragment;
 }
```

`Unable to find the default constructor on type MyProject.Adapters.ViewPagerFragment. **Please provide the missing constructor**. ---> Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.Java.Lang.Error: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Error' was thrown. --- End of managed exception stack trace ---java.lang.Error: Java callstack: at mono.android.TypeManager.n_activate(Native Method)   at mono.android.TypeManager.Activate(TypeManager.java:7)`

Comment: Thats not a constructor... Please post more of the class so we can tell you how to implement a constructor.

Comment: I have View pager with list of fragments. It is crashing on pause!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what the crash is, but a healthy `newInstance()` in java looks like this:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String a, String b) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_A, a);
    args.putString(ARG_B, b);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Also this line worries me:
`_Activity = Activity;` You should probably let the Android lifecycle methods handle that. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

But then again, I have no experience with Xamarin.